# Understanding how memory contents map into a struct

Tags: c++

I am not able to understand how bytes in memory are being mapped into a struct.
My machine is a little-endian x86_64. The code was compiled with gcc 4.7.0 from the Win64 mingw32-64 distribution for Win64.

These are contents of the relevant memory fragment:

...450002cf9fe5000040115a9fc0a8fe...

And this is the struct definition:

```
typedef struct ip4 {
    unsigned int ihl :4;
    unsigned int version :4;
    uint8_t tos;
    uint16_t tot_len;
    uint16_t id;
    uint16_t frag_off; // flags=3 bits, offset=13 bits
    uint8_t ttl;
    uint8_t protocol;
    uint16_t check;
    uint32_t saddr;
    uint32_t daddr;
    /*The options start here. */
} ip4_t;
```

When a pointer to such an structure (let it be `*ip4`) is initialized to the starting address of the above pasted memory region, this is what the debugger shows for the struct's fields:

```
ip4:          address=0x8da36ce
ip4->ihl:     address=0x8da36ce, value=0x5
ip4->version: address=0x8da36ce, value=0x4
ip4->tos:     address=0x8da36d2, value=0x9f
ip4->tot_len: address=0x8da36d4, value=0x0
...
```

I see how `ihl` and version are mapped: 4 bytes for a long integer, little-endian. But I don't understand how `tos` and `tot_len` are mapped; which bytes in memory correspond to each one of them.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: While it's commendable to understand how memory is handled internally, don't ever *count* on being able to access members from `ip4` by address offset.

Comment: `ihl` and `version` are both only 4 bits each (that's the first byte). So `tos` is 0, `tot_len` is 2cf, a bit later `protocol` is 11 (UDP). The memory fragment shows the ip-header discussed in http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc791.txt

Comment: The problem is that in the version compiled by me (and only in this version), as shown by the debugger, tot_len is not 2cf, but 0. This causes the whole program to execute wrongly. As they suggest below, there might be a problem with default alignment done by gcc... but I still have no idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tos`is mapped to 0x8da36d2, just 4 bytes after `ihl`, and it uses the byte at that address for storing the value `9f`. The compiler seems to use 16-bit alignment here, so the start of `tot_len` is **two** bytes later from `0x8da36d4` to `0x8da36d5`, and the value at `0x8da36d3` (which seems to be `e5`in your example) is just unused garbage.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. But I still did not solve the puzzle leading to my first question. When I repeat the above experiment but using a third-party compiled version of the code, something is different: version=0x5, tos=0x0 and tot_len=0x02cf (and these are real values, verified at the user level in the officially compiled version). As if the bitfields didn't take the 4 bytes, but only 1 byte. I guess there could be a manner of instructing gcc to solve this. There seem to be some macros that might control alignment of bitfields... could this the correct way to go?

Comment: @user95592: There are two possibilities: either the library instructs gcc to leave out all the padding from the struct, or more likely, the library *copies* the data from the buffer to the corresponding fields in the struct, taking into account that the struct might have padding between the fields.

Comment: Thanks. It has to be the first one, since there is not any difference between the officially released code and the one I am compiling on my own.

Comment: My goal is to switch off the 16-bit alignment causing (presumably) `tot-len` to be read at a further position than it should. I've tried `-fpack-struct` and `#pragma (pack)`, but they silently fail to change anything. The `packed` attribute is ignored by gcc (a warning informs about it during compilation). So far no desired effects at all. Any hints...?

Comment: @user95592: this is really a question better suited for stackoverflow.com, you should ask there.

Comment: I see. I hadn't noticed this site's specific focus on conceptual questions. Thanks.